# Filter Google Places API for only one country

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

Following the guide found https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#places_searchbox I am trying to filter my search box to only show suggestions for the UK.

I have the code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXX&libraries=places&callback=initialize&v=3"
        async defer></script>


<script>

    function initialize() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            initMap();
            initAutocomplete();
        }, 4000);

    }

    function initAutocomplete() {

        var options = {
            types: [],
            componentRestrictions: {country: 'GB' }
        };

        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input, options);

    }

</script>
```

Which works to the point that the search box gets initialised and is usable however its not filtering to just UK locations. The box will show locations recommendations for the world over.

Using GB or gb gives the same result

[image]

Comment: Their example (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#places_searchbox) says lowercase country: `componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}`. Try lowercasing it?

Comment: Can we filter by City addresses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end switching to

```
function initAutocomplete() {
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var options = {
            types: ['(cities)'],
            componentRestrictions: {country: 'GB'}
            };

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    }
```

fixed my issue

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try `setComponentRestrictions` method.

```
var options = {
  types: []
};

var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input, options);
// This method.
searchBox.setComponentRestrictions({'country': ['gb']});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the country lowercased:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXX&libraries=places&callback=initialize&v=3"
        async defer></script>


<script>
  document.onload = function initialize() {
      initMap();
      initAutocomplete();
    }

    function initAutocomplete() {

        var options = {
            types: [],
            componentRestrictions: {country: 'gb' }
        };

        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input, options);

    }

</script>
```

Comment: No dice same issue

Comment: It seems a little strange you are using a timeout call; is that the way the places API recommends being ready for the setup call? That might not be fully loaded despite waiting 4 seconds, perhaps this is causing some issue. Can you write it with `document.onload` instead to make sure the JS is properly loaded?

Comment: this gives me [Error] InvalidValueError: initialize is not a function
 Cg (js:96:131)
 (anonymous function) (js:162)
 Load (js:21)
 (anonymous function) (js:161)
 Global Code (js:162)

Answer (score 0):

If using api directly add &components=country:uk

e.g: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete